# Specify custom thousand separator to be culture independent

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I want to specify a custom thousand separator in C# and I want it to be culture independent.

The format string I want is: XXX.XXX,XX

e.g 1.134,43

Can Anyone suggest me something?

Thanks,
Panos.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "I want it to be culture independent"? This is a cultural setting - it sounds like you potentially want to create your own CultureInfo, or find one which already has the right number format.

Comment: Hi removed your tag in title, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: @John, Yes i guess you are right. what I meant was that I don't want the format to change depending on the culture. So do I need to create my own culture?

Comment: Just use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expression to check the format of your number, like this:

```
    // First we see the input string.
    string input = yourInputNumber.ToString();

    // Here we call Regex.Match.
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^\d{0,5}(\d\.\d?|\.\d)?\d?$",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // ...
    }
```